# pytest does not raise HTTPError using mock.patch

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, python-unittest

My code is as following:

```
import pytest
import requests
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('requests.get')
def test_verify(mock_request):
    mock_resp = mock.Mock()
    mock_resp.status_code = 404

    mock_request.return_value = mock_resp
    r = requests.get()

    with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as err_msg:
        r.raise_for_status()
    print(err_msg)
```

Since the status code of response is set to 404, I expect that a HTTPError will be raised. However, there is an error stating

```
Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>
```

The output is as following:

> ======================================== test session starts ======================================== platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.0, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.7.1 rootdir: /Users/michael/Code/youtube-data-api, inifile: plugins:
>   requests-mock-1.5.2 collected 1 item
>
> temp_test.py F
>   [100%]
>
> ============================================= FAILURES ==============================================
>   ____________________________________________ test_verify ____________________________________________
>
> mock_request =
>
> ```
> @mock.patch('requests.get')
> def test_verify(mock_request):
>     mock_resp = mock.Mock()
>     mock_resp.status_code = 404
>
>     mock_request.return_value = mock_resp
>     r = requests.get()
>     #print(r.status_code)
>
>     with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as err_msg:
>        r.raise_for_status() E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>
> ```
>
> temp_test.py:15: Failed
>   ===================================== 1 failed in 0.12 seconds ======================================

terminal output:
[image: terminal output]

Comment: Please copy and paste the output instead of giving a screenshot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mock_resp` is a `mock.Mock()` object. Calling `raise_for_status()` is just going to return another `Mock()`.

You'll need to use a response that preserves the original `raise_for_status()`. Try this:

```
import pytest
import requests
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch('requests.get')
def test_verify(mock_request):
    mock_resp = requests.models.Response()
    mock_resp.status_code = 404
    mock_request.return_value = mock_resp
    res = requests.get()
    with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as err_msg:
        res.raise_for_status()
    print(err_msg)
```

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother, but I have one more question. Why does it seem like mock_resp = mock.Mock() is a common practice? For example, it is used here https://gist.github.com/evansde77/45467f5a7af84d2a2d34f3fcb357449c

Comment: In short, just using a `mock.Mock()` is a quick way to return a mock object that you don't care what's called on it. That gist actually goes to lengths to mock out certain portions of the `Response()` api, so I'm not sure it really netted them much. You can see where they created a function to create a mock_response, which actually includes adding a `side_effect`. That `side_effect` would give the correct `raise_for_status` behavior if provided.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that your test is _kind of_ testing the requests library. IMO that might be a bit overkill, and mocking 'get' would be better suited for testing code that might operate on that mocked response.